# Import packages in Pyscript framework

Tags: python, pyscript

I have this html that uses Pyscript framework

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <title>PyScript Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
        - numpy
        - matplotlib
    </py-env>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-script>
        print('Hello World')
    </py-script>
    <py-script>
        a = 0
        b = 1
        for _ in range(10):
            print(a)
            a, b = b, a + b
    </py-script>
    <py-script>
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
        x, y = np.random.random(100), np.random.random(100)
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.gcf()
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when loading the page I got an error `JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 1, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' )` at the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the spaces and it worked well

```
    <py-env>
- numpy
- matplotlib  
    </py-env>  

  </head>
```

I think the problem is with using Tab before the dash. I tried using spaces instead and it worked with no problem at all.

[image]